# HtmlUnit failure: Attempted ImmediateRefreshHandler...OutOfMemoryError. Use WaitingRefreshHandler or ThreadedRefreshHandler instead

Tags: out-of-memory, htmlunit

StackOverflow forced me to shorten the actual exception text.  The full exception is:

> HtmlUnit: Attempted to refresh a page using an ImmediateRefreshHandler which could have caused an OutOfMemoryError Please use WaitingRefreshHandler or ThreadedRefreshHandler instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a tricky solution to find, so I'm posting it here.

Simply create your own empty RefreshHandler:

```
    RefreshHandler rh = new RefreshHandler() {
        void handleRefresh( final Page page, final URL url, final int seconds ) {}
    }
```

Then attach it to your web client:

```
    client.setRefreshHandler(rh)
```

Note that I did this in Groovy, so you might have to tweak the syntax for Java.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, problem with redirects presents even in the latest version 2.12. So you can simply disable redirects.

```
client.getOptions().setRedirectEnabled(false);
```